# Symfony2.6: Form handle a request with array data instead entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a FormType that creates checkboxes groups based on an array that is passed in the creation of that FormType:

```
//FormType.php

public function __construct(array $choices, array $choicesData)
{
    $this->choices = $choices;
    $this->choicesData = $choicesData;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    foreach ($this->choices as $bundle => $class) {
        $choiceBuilder = $builder->create($bundle, 'form', array('virtual' => true));
        foreach ($class as $name => $perm) {
            $choiceBuilder->add(
                    $name, 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => $perm,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'required' => 'false',
                    'label' => $name,
                    'data' => $this->choicesData[$bundle][$name]
                )
            );
        }
        $builder->add($choiceBuilder);
    }
    $builder->add('salvar', 'submit', array('label' => false));
}
```

**Notice:** No setDefaultOptions in Type.

Then I create the form:

```
//Controller.php

 $form = $this->createForm(new PermissaoType($choices, $choicesData), $choicesData);
```

**My Problem:** but when I making the **handleRequest()** of the data sent with POST **getData()** does not return the change of the form, only that which is set at **$choicesData**. Could anyone help me on this?

```
//Controller.php

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

    $form->handleRequest($request); // Not Work
    $data = $form->getData(); // Return $choicesData original
}
```

Example $choiceData original:

```
array(
    'group1' => array(
                    'item1' => array('chk1' => false, 'chk2' => false, 'chk3' => false)
    )
);
```

Example of form submitted:

```
array(
'group1' => array(
                'item1' => array( 0 => 'chk1', 1 => 'chk3')
    )
);
```

Example $choiceData returned (after $form->handleRequest() and $form->getData()):

```
array(
    'group1' => array(
                    'item1' => array('chk1' => false, 'chk2' => false, 'chk3' => false)
    )
);
```

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with changes below:

- Remove second $choicesData to **$this->createForm()**

  `$form = $this->createForm(new PermissaoType($choices, $choicesData));`
- `'data' => $this->choicesData[$bundle][$name]` to `'data' => array_keys(array_intersect($this->choicesData[$bundle][$name], array(true)))`
- In **FormType** I changed `'mapped' => false` to `'mapped' => true`

Thanks @Jovan Perovic

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you need to encapsulate passed `array` with form's name as a key.

For example, if you have something like this in your FormType class:

```
public function getName(){
    return 'some_form_name'
}
```

Then you should pass:

```
$data = array(
    'some_form_name' => $request->request->all() // Encapsulte `POST` data
);

$form->submit($data);
```

Or you could encapsulate the data when you send it. Then you could do by-the-book:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I tried this:`$form = $this->createForm(new PermissaoType($choices, $choicesData), array('Permissao'=>$choicesData));` But not work. Notice: 'Permissao' it's the name of FormType.